# How to find the next date PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table "UserState":

```
_id___|_ctime____________________________|_state__________|_userid
 1    | 2014-06-09 05:57:07.033334+00    | Ready          | 1
 2    | 2014-06-09 05:53:35.243864+00    | Busy           | 1
 3    | 2014-06-09 05:51:39.412722+00    | Ready          | 1
 4    | 2014-06-09 05:48:48.09651+00     | logged out     | 1
```

*ctime means the time of getting the new status by user.
This table means, that I have only the start time of state, but don't know to end time. 
The end time of the state is the start time of another one.

And I need an SQL query, that will provide me the following data for every state:

**userid | state | ctime | endtime**
considering the endtime as the starttime(ctime) of a next state

It's not possible to add new columns to the table "UserState". But it's possible, that user with (id = 1) may have state 'Ready' after the same state 'Ready', such states must be grouped into 1 row.

Comment: When the user with id #1 is grouped what is the `ctime`? The first or the last? That only happens with #1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A window function will do this:

```
select userid,
       state,
       ctime as start_time, 
       lead(ctime) over (partition by userid order by ctime) as end_time
from userstate;
```

If you are not used to window functions, please see the Postgres manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: @user3824666 this assumes that you want the next date.. that is not the *closest* date, what if the closest date comes before?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly, what [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) can do. This case, you can use the [`lead()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) function.

Comment: Thank you too. It's not always obvious for me, how window functions work.